# redux-observable epic that doesn't send any new actions

Tags: promise, action, rxjs, redux-observable

Might be that I'm a noob and not fully understanding how this stuff should work yet, but I have an epic in redux-observable in which I want to use as a way to create a promise which will dispatch an action and wait for a different action before resolving.  I've got it working by mapping the action to `'__IGNORE__'` but I really don't want to do that.  Is there any way to just have an epic handle an action, but not pass anything else on?

Here's my code:

```
export const waitFor = (type, action) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   const waitForResult = action$ => action$.ofType(type).do(() => resolve()).mapTo({type: "___IGNORE___"});
   registerEpic(waitForResult);

   action();
 });
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can throw away any next'd values from an observable chain by using the `.ignoreElements()` RxJS operator

```js
action$.ofType(type)
  .do(() => resolve())
  .ignoreElements();
```

Another way of doing this (no more right or wrong) is to create an anonymous Observable that just subscribes.

```js
const waitForResultEpic = action$ => new Observable(observer =>
  action$.ofType(type)
    .subscribe(() => resolve())
);
```

This is implicitly returning the subscription we create, so that it's attached to the lifecycle of our rootEpic as well. Because we never call `observer.next()`, this epic never emits any values; just like `ignoreElements()`.

---

Although you didn't ask, you may eventually notice that your epic will run forever, listening for that incoming action matching the `type` variable. This may not be not what you want, if you want to match *once* then complete.

You can accomplish that using [`.take(1)`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-take) operator.

```js
const waitForResult = action$ =>
  action$.ofType(type)
    .take(1)
    .do(() => resolve())
    .ignoreElements();
```

Or

```js
const waitForResult = action$ => new Observable(observer =>
  action$.ofType(type)
    .take(1)
    .subscribe({
      next: () => resolve(),
      error: err => observer.error(err),
      complete: () => observer.complete()
    })
);
```

This will only match once per the life of the application--once received it will never do it again.